# Replace unicode characters in html returned from node js web scraper

Tags: javascript, unicode, cheerio

I have a web scraper that uses cheerio. My goal is to get a list of all the links on the page, however I have noticed that some links do not show up due to unicode greater than and less than characters replacing the opening and closing tags.

How would I best replace these instances of unicode? I have tried the normalize() method but this does not seem to work.

Here is the code

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { load } from 'cheerio'

const response = await fetch('https://www.kapow.com/')
const html = await response.text()
const $ = load(html)

const links = $('a')
  .map((i, link) => link.attribs.href)
  .get()

console.log(links)
```

Here is a screenshot of the unicode characters I am trying to replace highlighted in blue. Ideally I would be able to replace all the unicode such as \u003c and \u003e:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

replace with regex range:

```
"\u003c".replace(/[\u003a-\u003e]/g, '')
```

also:

```
const links = $('a').get().map(a => $(a).attr('href'))
```

Comment: hmmm regex range replacement does not seem to work, although I will take a look at just using the replace method

Comment: you can paste that line in your browser console to verify that it works.